# what exceptions to handle when configuring retry for mass transit

Tags: c#, masstransit

When configuring UseScheduledRedelivery in a mass-transit consumer. what is the best practice for what should be handled.

Is handling Exception overkill? and is there a list of exceptions that can proberbly be recovered from?

Comment: In general; only handle exceptions that you would expect by design. Throw all others.

Comment: The point of handling exceptions is that you can act accordingly, based on what you need to happen. How to handle it is inherently up to you to decide. If you don't want to handle an exception or wouldn't know what to do when you encounter it, **then don't handle it**. Throwing an exception should inherently mean that there is no way to work around the error state that was encountered (hence why the exception is thrown, in order to **stop** executing a method as it can no longer yield any meaningful results).

Comment: What I am talking about is handling retry attempts in a distributed system. If you get a deadlock. And try again in 100ms it will proberbly work. If the consumer is rebooting. In 5 mins it will proberbly stop timing out and work. There are heaps of exceptions that you don't know about and van recover from by just received trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redelivery is second-level retry. It means that it handles exceptions that are not recovered by first-level retry (retry policies).

Basically, you probably want to retry everything except exceptions that are caused by your message data. However, even null reference exceptions can be subject of retries. For example, you have a database and you try to get a record and get null. This can be because the record is not there yet, but it will come later since there is a message in the queue to create it. So, race conditions can lead to such exceptions.

Second-level retries, however, are different. You want to use them to overcome, for example, issues with resource starvation (busy database or something). These exceptions are very specific, like network timeout exception or database timeout exception. But there is no "list", you need to look at your system design to decide where you apply first-level retries and where you use second-level retries, and which exceptions are handled by those.

We use retries for all exceptions and redelivery for a very small number of exceptions and not in all services. Usually we redeliver after getting database timeout.